# Huge discrepancy between Python time.clock() and Sublime Text 2 timing

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm trying to compare the run times of two different algorithms for determining whether a number is prime, using Python's time module, for example:

```
test = primesComparisonTXT()
start = time.clock()
print 'Fermat Method'
for prime in test:
    print isFermatProbablePrime(prime, 5)
total = time.clock() - start
print total
```

primesComparisonTXT() is a function that returns a list of the confirmed primes in (1, 1000000).

isFermatProbablePrime() is a function that takes in 1. a suspected prime 2. a parameter that indicates how many times that suspected prime should be tested for primality using Fermat's primality test. The function returns True or False depending whether the suspect is a probable prime. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)

The algorithm correctly outputs that every prime in that list is indeed a probable prime, but I'm getting largely different results for the timing. 4.57107920129 is what's printed as "total," but Sublime Text states that the build was "[Finished in 15.1s]". Sublime's timing is more accurate. Is there any particular reason for this discrepancy; perhaps a better timing method should be used (timeit)?

Comment: How long does `primesComparisonTXT()` take?

Comment: 0.0783992072275s according to time.clock(), 0.3s according to Sublime

Comment: You should use time.time() if you want the actual duration.

Comment: Or, if you're trying to test the time for a complete script, just use the `time` command, which will actually show you both clock time and processor time, the latter broken down into user and sys/kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you should expect. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) say:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name…

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/clock.html) says that the C function:

> … shall return the implementation's best approximation to the processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the process invocation.

In other words, this is *processor* time, not wall-clock time. If your processor is doing anything else (like, say, running other programs), or waiting around doing nothing while your program blocks on I/O, it isn't counted.

Actually, it's even worse than that—such time *may* be counted on some Unix and Unix-like systems, and *will* be counted on Windows… so if you don't understand your platform, it's not necessarily easy to understand what `clock` actually means.

At any rate, the time reported by `clock` should be <= the wall-clock time, not ==.

Comment: So Sublime's timing is wall-clock time?

Comment: @djlovesupr3me: Most likely, yes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do timing in python.

Use the timeit module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Wrap your code up in a function, and use:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("primefunction()", setup='from mymodule import primefunction')

#or
timeit.timeit(primefunction)
```

Comment: Or just `timeit.timeit(primefunction)`.

Comment: Why does the time documentation state that for time.clock(): "...but in any case, this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms"?

Comment: No idea. That's what timeit is for.

Comment: @djlovesupr3me: First, that's because you're looking at the 2.x docs; note that [3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) explicitly deprecates `clock`. Second, this is the function you'd use (in 2.7) _if you wanted to build something like `timeit` yourself_. But doing it right is more complicated than just subtracting two `clock` values. You can read what `timeit` does (in the docs, or the source)—but unless you know what you're doing and need to do something different, just use `timeit`.